# Programs opening but not visible

Tags: boot, unity, command-line, launcher

```
OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Processor: Intel® Core™2 CPU 6320 @ 1.86GHz × 2 
Graphics: Intel® 965Q
OS type: 64-bit
```

I have spent about a week researching a solution to my problem, which only occurred after upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04. Every article I have read online, has not resolved my issue. Neither has a fresh install from live CD. I am able to boot and login successfully but some programs activated (either from dash, launcher or terminal) are not available. These are programs like Gimp, System Monitor, and Gparted.

Even when I have tried to re-burn my ISO file, my CD/DVD is not recognised in Startup Disk Creator. The brand is recognised, but says it only has 2MB of memory, when it has up to 4.7GB. I have tried different disks and all are recognised as only having 2MB of memory, even though the brand of the disk is proven to change.

Everything only seems to work after a fresh install of the ISO (from live CD) and I re-install my back-up files. All programs work perfectly. Then I shut down or logout and into a new user, and that's when I can no longer access programs. I can open them through all the methods available, but the window doesn't open on desktop. The icon locks to the launcher as if the program is open, with the outline of a triangle, rather than the full triangle I get next to Firefox and Thunderbird, which I can always open without issue.

From my research, the outline of a triangle next to the icon in launcher, means the program is open, but its at a different location. When I use Ctrl-Alt-Tab, I can see the window has clearly been activated as if it is operational, but I cannot access the window from my desktop. I only have one monitor, so the information is not being redirected to a second monitor, as I've read has been the case for some.

Upon reading another article, I followed advice issuing commands in terminal (I cannot remember which command, I apologise) but the output was *"Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"* This gave my first indication the system is perhaps operating under two identities, or my xsessions are not being executed properly, thus causing a misfire to home directory.

I have tried creating a new user and installing my back-up files there, but the same problem occurs after logging out or shutting down. I have also tried installing kubuntu in an attempt to resolve issues which may be occurring in unity - but I have the same problem of the program opening, but no window making it accessible to the user. I even tried GNOME but the only thing visible was the wallpaper.

Although I can boot without problem, I will include the URL issued after completing Boot Repair, in case it has information which can help.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10988025/

If you require further information please ask. I will need specific commands to enter into terminal to retrieve the information, however.

*(steeldriver, identified the conflict below)

Comment: It sounds kind of like something in your Home directory is messing Ubuntu up. Instead of moving the whole folder back, just move Documents, Desktop and Downloads. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Zacharee1. What do you mean by move the folder back? I originally thought it might have something to do with the folders I was restoring through backups. So I did a fresh install of the OS without restoring my original files. It still exhibited the same behaviour. So I'm not importing the problem. Would your suggestion still alter the outcome? I would love to try it, but I'll need an explanation of where/how I move the folders.

Comment: Hmm. Even a completely fresh install, format and everything?

Comment: I've installed about five times now, and all the same result once I restart or logout to a new user.  I  thought for sure it would work if I didn't install my backup files, but its the same result on a fresh install once I log out or restart the system again.

Comment: Have you formatted the partition before installing?

Comment: Do you mean through "Disks". I haven't actually done that and wondered if it was possible to format File system partition 1, while it was mounted? I only have access to Disks, not Gparted when I have these problems.

Comment: It does sound a lot like a multi-monitor issue - is it possible that your system *thinks* you have multiple displays, even though you don't? what do you see in the display settings panel (or `unity-control-center display` from the command line)?

Comment: Nothing comes out at terminal, but the Screen Display activates on Settings. I seem to have two monitors, one is pink, the other is green. The green is highlighted and says Acer Technologies 19". I am stumped as to why I have two screens which say the same thing. I can only choose one or the other though. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

It was my system registering two active screens, through Settings --> Screen Display. Both were switched to the "on" position. I just had to switch one screen off, ensuring the other was switched on, then save the changes.

Magic! Thank you Zacharee1 for getting the ball rolling, and steeldriver for finding the solution.

Comment: Steeldriver wrote it as a comment rather than answer, so you're unable to accept it as an answer and give him credit.  Since *this* answer answers the question, you should mark it as accepted (even though it's your own answer).  If you don't want to be seen as stealing someone else's reputation, you can mark your answer as "community wiki" and you won't get points for it.

Comment: And of course if steeldriver does end up turning his comment into an answer you can always change the accepted answer to his.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation thomasrutter. I would like steeldriver to get the points, so I'll wait a few days to see if they want to formulate an answer, which I can mark up.  Otherwise I will mark it as community wiki afterwards. I cannot see a button for that near my answer though.

Comment: There is an option to mark as community wiki when you edit your answer.  It's a tiny little checkbox on the right near the main editing field.